# OracleBulkCopy Memory Leak(OutOfMemory Exception)

Tags: c#, oracle, memory-leaks, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

Below is the code I used to bulkcopy data from a temp table dataTable into a destTable in Oracle Database. The dataTable has about 2 million records.

```
using (OracleBulkCopy bulkCopy = new OracleBulkCopy(VMSDATAConnectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (OracleBulkCopyColumnMapping columnMapping in columnMappings)
                        bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(columnMapping);

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = destTableName;
                    //bulkCopy.BatchSize = dataTable.Rows.Count;
                    //bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 100;                   
                    int defaultSize = 5000;
                    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OracleBulkCopyBatchSize"], out defaultSize);
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = defaultSize;
                    int timeOut = 100;
                    int.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OracleBulkCopyTimeout"], out timeOut);
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = timeOut;
                    Console.WriteLine("Bulk insert from {0} to {1} started at: {2}\r\nBatchSize : {3}, BulkCopyTimeout : {4} ", dataTable.TableName, destTableName, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"), bulkCopy.BatchSize.ToString(), bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout.ToString());
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
                    Console.WriteLine("Bulk insert from {0} to {1} finished at: {2}", dataTable.TableName, destTableName, DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error happened during bulk copy from {0} to {1}\r\nBatchSize : {2}, BulkCopyTimeout : {3}\r\n Error message {4}", dataTable.TableName, destTableName, bulkCopy.BatchSize.ToString(), bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout.ToString(), ex.ToString());
                    bulkCopy.Close();
                    bulkCopy.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

But it throws following exception: 
[image]

The server running this data loading process definitely has enough memory, it looks like the database server (linux) does not have enough memory. Below is the database server memory screen shot:
[image]

Can anyone help with this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Judging by your stacktrace the OutOfMemoryException is completely unrelated to the code you've posted.  The stacktrace says that the static constructor of the `UCMExec.Utility` class is what is throwing the exception.  Please edit the question and include the source of this static constructor.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Modified my code and get more information, the exception was threw from bulkCopy.WriteToServer function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the root cause, the exe is running in 32 bit and it has a 1.5G memory limit. Need to change the target platform and replace Oracle.DataAccess.dll to 64 bit version.

Also there is an alternative solution: load data in batch so it will not exceed 1.5 G memory limit.

Update:

"MEMORY LEAK USING ORACLEBULKCOPY": the oracle bulk copy has some bug that causes memory leak, it happens when the BatchSize is less than datatable size.
Need to modify the BatchSize or update ODAC to higher version.

Reference: https://community.oracle.com/message/4593452#4593452